# method iterating another methods in python

Tags: python, methods, generator

I do some coding for measurements, I have a class of samples, and each method within this class is some actual measurement, like

```
sample = Sample()
sample.measure_ivc(*args)
```

Now I want to repeat a certain measurement for a set of external parameters, say, temperature. Ideally, it should look like

```
sample.measure_ivc(*args).iterate_T(T_list)
```

or

```
sample.iterate_T(T_list).measure_ivc(*args)
```

I have many different measurement procedures, so I want to avoid defining `measure_ivc_T()` for each of them.
Of course, I can pass measurement method name and its args to `iterate_method_over_T()`, but it looks messy, especially when `iterate_T()` requires its own args.

The most elegant solution I came up so far is

```
class Sample():

   def ivc(self, *args) :
       print(' meas ivc')

       return 

   def iterate_T(self, T_list):

       for t in T_list:
           print (f'set T to {t}')

        yield self
```

but it works only like that

```
sample = Sample()
[s.ivc(*args) for s in sample.iterate_T(T_list)]
```

Can it be better/closer to my request?

Comment: It's not clear to me how `T_list` is involved here

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I want to iterate over T in T_list, i.e call measure_ivc() at each T

Comment: I don't know what you want to do.Could you show us a simple of `T_list` and what is your expected result?

Comment: `T_list` is just a list of values of temperature I want to set before each `measure_ivc`. In other words, I want to define a method, which iterates another method and does smthg else between iterations. It's trivial with `for T in T_list : set(T), measure_Ivc()`, but I wonder if there's something neater and more pythonic